# No networking at all (wifi and ethernet)

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I started using ubuntu 17.04 after switching from windows about a month ago , and as soon as i installed ubuntu i had problems with my wifi. I have RTL8821AE networking card and had to install third party drivers from [here](https://medium.com/@elmaxx/rtl8821ae-wifi-drivers-in-ubuntu-16-04-4c1286524afa).
The wifi didn't work great as i had to restart my wifi about 2-3 times a day as it just stopped working , but a restart did the job.
Today my wifi didn't work so i restarted it but it didn't come back up.
After opening nmtui there was no wifi or wired tab at all. Tried connecting wired didn't work. Please help me.

Some command i ran :

**ifconfig**

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1760  bytes 135548 (135.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1760  bytes 135548 (135.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**iwconfig**

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d58 (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**lshw**

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 10
       serial: c8:5b:76:5a:dd:d3
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:126 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: 78:45:61:eb:b8:ab
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.10.0-33-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b1003fff
```

Comment: Probably, you just need to reinstall that driver, and repeat after every kernel update.

Comment: I will try but Does the kernal update automatically ? Also , i installed the driver to fix my wifi , ethernet worked just fine.

Comment: I tried reinstalling them and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the network-manager networking was disabled in the config.
Had to turn off network-manager service , go the network-manager.state file , turn on networking and start the network-manager service again.